# dynamically change the href of all links on the page to open the primary link and secondary link at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, href

my web page has many buttons and links like so:

```
<div class="box"> 
<a href="http://foo.com/index.php/products/view/bar">
<div class="bar" style="margin-top:337px;cursor:pointer;"></div></a> 
</div>
```

and i would like a javascript script that would go through the page and dynamically add a second link to the href so it would be

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://foo.com/index.php/products/view/bar');
    window.open('bar.com');"></a>
```

on each link in the page.

I have many pages in my site so would very much like if someone could show me how to do this by just implementing a javascript segment in the `<head>` section and have it dynamically change all the links on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just pretend you have an A tag "`<a href="http://foo.com/index.php/products/view/bar">a</a>`"

```
var createDelegate = function (obj, handler) {
                return function () { return handler.apply(obj, arguments); };
            };

            var changeHref = function () {
                var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
                for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
                    hrefs[i].attachEvent('onclick', createDelegate(hrefs[i], function () { openLink(this); return false; }));
                }
            }

        var openLink = function (obj) {
            var str = new String(obj.href);
            str = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            window.open(obj.href);
            window.open(str + '.com');
        }
```

// call it when loaded.

```
 changeHref();
```

Comment: http://foo.com/index.php/products/view/bar changes each time, how can i make it dynamically change every time depending on the link currency in the href?